If $\mu\perp\nu$, is it true that $\mu |_\mathcal{B}\perp\nu |_\mathcal{B}$ for every $\mathcal{B}$ sub-$\sigma$-algebra?
Let's suppose that we have a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ and two measures $\mu,\nu:\Sigma\rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ such that $\mu\perp\nu$, i.e. that exists $A,B\in\Sigma$ such that $\{A,B\}$ is a partition of $X$ and $\mu(A)=\nu(B)=0$.
I was wondering if, given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\Sigma$, the same property is valid for the restriction of the measures, i.e. $\mu |_\mathcal{B}\perp\nu |_\mathcal{B}$. Using the definition, this means that we have to find another partition $A',B'\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $\mu(A')=\nu(B')=0$.
It seems to me that this should be true, since the singularity looks like an intrinsic property of the measures, rather than the $\sigma$-algebra on which they are defined, and also because if the intuition behind the singularity is that the two measures "live" on disjoint sets, restricting the $\sigma$-algebra (and so the possible choice of sets on which the measures are defined) should reinforce this intuition.
The problem is that I don't know how to prove this: for a "constructive" proof I have no idea how to search for the sets $A',B'\in \mathcal{B}$, and at the same time a proof by contradiction doesn't seem to go anywhere.
I also tried to think about counterexamples to this, but nothing came to my mind.

It is not true with the definition you gave. You can always consider the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr A=\{\varnothing,X\}$, which is always contained in $\Sigma$. The only partition of $X$ is then $\varnothing,X$, but unless one of your measures is identically zero, then $X$ always has positive measure.
